# How to extend core classes in framework

Tags: php, design-patterns, frameworks, php-5.3

I've been using my own make PHP 5.3 web application framework and I must say it's quite a joy to work with. I'm actually thinking that go open source with it and allow others to feel the same joy I do ;)

Here's my problem. How important is it that all core classes must be extendable and what is a **good** way to accomplish this? Codeigniter uses the singleton pattern EVERYWHERE and that's out of the question. Kohanas filesystem is sweet but include way to many files (empty classes) for my taste.

I've never used Symfony but I heard that it takes advantage of Dependency Injection? I'm nott a guru on that topic but have some knowledge. Is this the way to go? Is there a 'smarter' way?

P.S. I'm using PHP 5.3 with namespaces, closures etc.

/ Tobias (a Swede in development)

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [Symfony2](http://symfony-reloaded.org/), [Lithium](http://lithify.me/) and [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), I think that they are the best with regards to design. I would advise against the use of singletons and use dependency injection instead.

> How important is it that all core classes must be extendable and what is a good way to accomplish this?

It really depends on the classes responsibilities. It's possible you might not want some core components in your MVC stack (assuming it's MVC) to be extended and you could declare them as final, or declare certain methods as final and force extension through plugins and helpers. Other classes maybe be designed to be extend, in which case they should be declared as abstract.

IMO, you should primarily be using protected properties and provide accessor methods. But don't just use protected visibility on all your properties, it's okay for some to be public and private, again it all comes down to responsibility.

All considering how much responsibility a class has, if it's serving multiple roles/purposes, it's time to refactor and split that class into too or more classes. And don't forget to use interfaces!

> I'm actually thinking that go open source with it and allow others to feel the same joy I do ;)

Before you go releasing your code consider the following:

- Is all my code unit tested?
- Do I use version control?
- Do I have complete API documentation?

I hate to be a downer, but if you answered 'no' to any of those questions don't bother about open sourcing your code properly because no one will use it. Maybe just start using GitHub for SCM. Also consider that there are already heaps of top-notch frameworks out there, why would they use your instead?

Also be sure to read [Top ten reasons why I wont use your open source project](http://thechangelog.com/post/3032074343/top-ten-reasons-why-i-wont-use-your-open-source-project).

...I'm just trying to save you from putting the extra, unnecessary effort into your project for public use when you won't get any traction anyway.

Comment: I see your point but that's very depressing to read. Hope we still have some "reinveters" left so new open source projects appears :/ I've taken a look at Symfony2, Li3 and believe that dependency injection is the way to go. I've already started integrate it and it looking pretty good. :) Thank you for a good answer. / Tobias

Comment: Don't worry, a majority of developers continually go through this stage, I've been there too, and probably will again at some stage. It's depressing, but it's the truth. As I said, if you want to OS your project just start using GitHub, but don't go making a dedicated website for your framework. Fabien Potencier made a good DI container: [Pimple](https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple) you should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the way the Zend Framework do this: There is mostly an abstract class (to extend it) and an concrete class (for the concrete use cases), e.g. the Db Mapper:

You could extend the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract class:

```
class Bugs extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'bugs';
}
```

Or if you just need simple functions, you could create a new Db Table Object this way:

```
$bugTable = new Zend_Db_Table('bug'); 
// Zend_Db_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
```

So you have to create two classes for every type in your solutions: the abstract and the concrete class.

More Info:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html